# why this shell script program is not working

Tags: command-line, scripts

```
echo "enter one no"
read n

rem='expr $n % 2'


if [ $rem -eq 0 ]

then
    echo "Number $n is even"
else
    echo "Number $n is odd"
fi
```

while executing this program , bash is showing message like "too many arguement ".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you are doing:

```
if [ expr $n % 2 -eq 0 ]
```

How come?

Because

```
rem='expr $n % 2'
```

is assigning variable `rem` as string `expr $n % 2`.

You need, command substitution:

```
rem=$(expr $n % 2)
```

Also use `bash`'s native arithmetic operator instead of `expr`:

```
rem=$(( $n % 2 ))
```

Answer (score 0):

- use read's built in prompt feature `read -p "Enter one num" n`
- prefer using `$( . . .)` , single quotes don't expand commands. `rem="$(expr $n % 2)"`
- Quote the variables when using them `"$rem"`
- use at most one line of break between `if` and `then`

  `if [ "$rem" -eq 0 ]
  then`